# Could anyone explain why this is a general case of Weierstrass Approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, approximation

Suppose $X_1, X_2 ...$ are independent Bernoulli random variables. with probability $p$ and $1-p$.
Let $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$.

If $U \in C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, then $E(U(\bar{X_n}))$ converges  uniformly  to $ U(E(\bar{X_n})) = U(p).$

Our professor used this as a "general case of Weierstrass approximation" and it was proved. But I still don't understand very much.

What is the polynomial here?

What is the meaning of $E(U(\bar{X_n}))$ converges  uniformly  to $ U(E(\bar{X_n}) = U(p)?$

Comment: I suspect the polynomial appears in the technique of proving convergence, in that the continuous function $U$ was approximated by a (sequence of) polynomials, the expected value was established for the polynomials, and then by a limiting argument, the convergence for $U$ follows.  Not seeing your notes on how the professor filled in the proof, I don't know if I could do more than speculate further about how to fill in those missing steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial here is $E(U(\bar X_n))$. Writing it out, this is
$$
E(U(\bar X_n))=\sum_{k=0}^n U(k/n)P(\bar X_n=k/n)\tag1$$
since $\bar X_n$ takes values in $0/n, 1/n,\ldots k/n$. If we write
$$P(\bar X_n=k/n)=P(n\bar X_n=k)$$
we see that $n\bar X_n=\sum_i X_i$ is a binomial($n,p$) random variable, so the sum (1) becomes the polynomial
$$\sum_{k=0}^n U(k/n){n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.\tag2$$
Note that the coefficients $U(k/n)$ are constants. The convergence is uniform in $p$, in the sense
$$\sup_{p\in[0,1]} \left | E(U(\bar X_n))-U(p) \right | \to 0\ \text{as $n\to\infty$.}
$$
The remark your prof made is that (2) is an explicit construction of the $n$th approximating polynomial (the [Bernstein polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial)) in the Weierstrass theorem.